# Integrate Hybris to SAP for Retail using SAP Cloud Platform Integration (SCPI)

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, hybris-data-hub, sap-cpi

I am trying to integrate SAP Hybris (1811) to SAP for Retail (ISR) using SAP Cloud Platform Integration (SCPI). Any good trail for this?

Regards, Wajih

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what adapters(HTTP,SOAP,SFTP) you want to pass the data with.
For more info you can check [this](https://help.sap.com/viewer/368c481cd6954bdfa5d0435479fd4eaf/Cloud/en-US/2fb0aa4dc5194b589adcd1c5534901e3.html).

If you want technical help, you can mail your query to `esb.users@listserv.sap.corp`.